# What is the largest 12 digit palindrome number divisible by 7?

Tags: mathematics, palindrome

A palindrome number is a number that is the same forwards as backwards. Some examples are 3443, 12321, and 59095.

Here's my question:
What is the largest 12 digit palindrome that is evenly divisible by 7?

Comment: Vote to close as a math Q

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would appear that the largest 12 digit number, 999,999,999,999 is divisible by 7 and is also a palindrome. So that must be the largest 12 digit palindrome divisible by 7

Answer (score 7):

999,999,999,999 as Stephen mentioned is divisible by 7. Just for fun, here are the next nine largest ones:

```
999992299999
999989989999
999982289999
999979979999
999972279999
999969969999
999962269999
999959959999
999952259999
```

If we're not allowing for repeated digits in each half, the largest ten would be:

```
987654456789**
987634436789
987624426789
987614416789
987604406789
987563365789
987543345789
987523325789
987513315789
987503305789
```

** = I just find it interesting that in both cases, the largest acceptable answer is unaffected by the "divisible by 7" clause.